Access logs show a malicious IP address accessing www.googletagmanager.com
I was reviewing the access logs for my website and found the below entry
45.148.10.59 - - [26/Jul/2024:07:46:49 -0500] "GET //www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id= HTTP/1.1" 200 12098 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.54 Safari/535.2" cpanel.<mydomain>.com <my_shared_hosting_ip>

I checked the source IP address and it seems to be a malicious IP address. The access logs show several entries from that IP address.
My understanding is that the IP address sent a request to my cpanel..com? asking for "www.googletagmanager.com/gtm..." and the response was HTTP 200. I don't have google tag manager. I am confused why the response was 200. Shouldn't it be 404?
I searched online for clues about this entry, but all I found was generic explanation of the log entry. Nothing specifically addressing this specific access attempt.
I would appreciate if someone could explain what happened here and share some insights on how concerned should I be and what can I do to prevent similar attempts in the future.

Looks like this is what that bot tried to find: yoursite.com//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id= Not sure why they would expect this folder to be there. That is not how gtm script is normally hosted.  Maybe some poorly written logic for automatic privacy concerns scanner to then try and wrestle some money from sites that don't do privacy right?
Why did your web server respond with 200? Probably poor CMS config. You can check it manually.
Checked that ip, here's the result:
The IP address 45.148.10.59 was blocked by the system more than 220 times.

Previously, a client from this address was identified as "SonyEricssonW580i/R6BC Browser/NetFront/3.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1".

The address belongs to the provider Pptechnology Limited, country code: NL.

Causes of blocking:

Content Scrapers

As expected, some poorly implemented web scraper.
But just in case, check that folder. That may as well be a concealed backdoor like r57 or whatever it's called. Oh, someone made a whole list of them here nice. That would be a nice way to conceal it given how few webmasters can distinguish between backend and frontend. You should never expect any gtm/google tag manager on your backend.
